# Calling WebService in Window Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am calling a web service in a window service using c#. Everything looks good but when  the window service is installed and I try to start the window service then it says 'The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion'.

Comment: usually this means that there was an unhandled exception during the startup of the service. Take a look at the eventviewer (Windows Logs -> Application) where the unhandled exception should be logged.

Comment: I have not worked with windows services before, but you could consider using asynchronous methods to open the WebService without without blocking the thread waiting for the OnOpened to return.

Comment: Add some more code and information so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: If everything goes well when debugging in Visual Studio, but it stops working after being installed as a Windows Service, one possibility is that in Visual Studio the app is run as the current user, while as a Windows Service, it's (often) run as the built-in account [Local System]/[Local Service]. This leads to problem if your app depends on something user-specific, e.g. the Web Service requires you import a certificate, but you only import it to the current user instead of the local computer, or the certificate is not accessible to the account running the Windows Service.

Comment: You can verify if it's the "user-specific" case by running the service as your current user. Go to 'services.msc', find your service, bring up "Properties" dialog and in the "Log On" tab, select "Log on as" ... "This Account" and input the credentials of your current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service shouldn't DO anything real in the start method.  It should start a timer to handle the real work.

There can be all sorts of network dependencies that aren't started when Windows tries to start your service.

An easy way to test this is to start the service manually after the system is up and running.  If it starts properly then, you need to either update the service dependencies or move the functionality out of the start method.

If it still fails, you've got an unhandled error condition somewhere in your start method.